# Create a JSON from a servers response using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, node.js

I get this response from a remote server.

```
A has 100 products\n   Brought: \n      ID/234 has brought 8 products\n      ID/212 has brought 72 products\n   Not Brought\n\n B has 0 products\n   Brought\n   Not Brought\n
```

When I execute my node js script on the terminal this response is displayed as a table as shown in the screenshot below.

[image]

I want this output as JSON.

Here is my code.

```
function(err, res) {
        product=res.content; //store the response in variable
        var prodArr = [];
        var obj = product.split('\n'); //split the response at new lines
    for(var i= 1; i<obj.length; i=i+1)
    {
                prodArr.push({
                    data : obj[i]
                 });

            }
        console.log(prodArr);
    })
}
```

And here the JSON I get when I execute the above script.

```
{ data:'A has 100 products' },
{ data: 'Brought: '},
{ data:'ID/234 has brought 8 products ' },
{ data:'ID/212 has brought 72 products ' },
{ data: 'Not Brought' },
{ data:'B has 0 products' },
{ data: 'Brought: '},
{ data: 'Not Brought '},
```

But I want JSON which should be something like this as shown below :

```
{
"data":{
  "title": "A has 100 products",
"Brought": {
"1" : "ID/234 has brought 8 products",
"2" : "ID/212 has brought 72 products"
},
"Not Brought" : {
    }
 }
},

{
"data":{
  "title": "B has 0 products",
"Brought": {
},
"Not Brought" : {
    }
 }
}
```

How do I do that?

Comment: Hi! Please read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) The code you've shown doesn't do anything to create the output you've said you want. Build up the object structure in memory, then use `JSON.stringify` to create the JSON for it. Your best bet here is to do your research, [search](/help/searching) for related topics on SO, and give it a go. ***If*** you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [mcve] of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help.

Comment: When you clicked to create this post the button said "Ask Question". But "I want" or "I need" is not a question. "How do I" is generally too broad and vague, unless it's something very very simple. We will help you fix bugs, not just do your work for you completely. What research have you done? What code have you tried? What problem are you facing? Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for further guidance on how to ask a useful question.

Comment: Basically though you need to start checking the content of each line before you blindly add it to the array, and using that to decide what step you're at in building your object, and then act accordingly. Try writing yourself some simple rules for how you (as a human) would manually process the data into the structure you want - write it as if you're describing it to someone you'll never speak to in person (i.e. thoroughly and without ambiguities, so they don't have to ask you). That gives you your requirements and process. After that, try to turn that into JavaScript code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use regex to figure out the position of title elements and the brought and not brought items as the solution is completely specific.

```js
var input = "A has 100 products\n   Brought: \n      ID/234 has brought 8 products\n      ID/212 has brought 72 products\n   Not Brought\n\n B has 0 products\n   Brought\n   Not Brought\n";
var splitInput = input.split('\n'); // split with newline
var formattedInput = splitInput.map(slice => slice.trim()); // trim extra spaces
var titleIndices = [], broughtIndices = [], notBroughtIndices = []; // figure out necessary indices in string
for(var i = 0; i < formattedInput.length; i++) {
 if(/\w+ has \d+ products/.test(formattedInput[i])){
    titleIndices.push(i);
  }
 if(/^Brought\:?/.test(formattedInput[i])) {
  broughtIndices.push(i);
 }
 if(/^Not Brought\:?/.test(formattedInput[i])) {
  notBroughtIndices.push(i);
 }
}
const output = [];
for(var i = 0; i < titleIndices.length; i++) {
  const broughtLength = notBroughtIndices[i] - broughtIndices[i] - 1;
  let brought = {};
  for(var j=0; j < broughtLength; j++) {
    const broughtItem = formattedInput[broughtIndices[i]+1+j];
    if(broughtItem) {
     brought[j+1] = broughtItem;
    }
  }
  const notBroughtLength = (titleIndices[i+1] || notBroughtIndices[i] ) - notBroughtIndices[i] - 1;
  let notBrought = {};
  for(var j=0; j < notBroughtLength; j++) {
    const notBroughtItem = formattedInput[notBroughtIndices[i]+1+j]
    if (notBroughtItem) {
    notBrought[j+1] = notBroughtItem;
  }
  }
 output.push({
  data: {
    title: formattedInput[titleIndices[i]],
    Brought: brought,
    "Not Brought": notBrought,
  }
 });
}
console.log(JSON.stringify(output))
```

Comment: thanks a lot. I used the logic from your code and it worked for me

Comment: can you help me with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53700568/angularjs-custom-filter-to-check-for-values-inside-a-data-array)

Answer (score 1):

```js
var InputValue=['A has 100 Product','Brought','ID/1251 brought 8 Product','ID/1252 brought 4 Product','Not Brought','B has 100 Product','Brougth','ID/1222 brought 8 Product','ID/1333 brought 2 Product','Not Brought']
var prodArr={};
var finalResult=[];
var BroughtArr=[]
let i=0;
for(i=0;i<InputValue.length;i++){
    if(i==0){
         prodArr['Title']=InputValue[0];
         i++;
    }
    if(InputValue[i]==='Brought'){
       ++i;
       for(let j=i;j<InputValue.length;j++){
          if(InputValue[j]!='Not Brought'){
           BroughtArr.push(InputValue[j]);
         }else{
           prodArr['Brought']=BroughtArr
           finalResult.push(prodArr);
           BroughtArr=[]
           prodArr={}
           if(i<InputValue.length)
           prodArr['Title']=InputValue[++j];
           i=++j;
         } 
       }
     }
}
console.log(finalResult)
```